# How to parse a String to a Date in Swift 5.6 using Date.ParseStrategy?

Tags: swift, date, parsing

I would like to parse a `yyyyMMdd` formatted date.

```
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(
    format: "\(year: .defaultDigits)\(month: .twoDigits)\(day: .twoDigits)",
    locale: Locale(identifier: "fr_FR"),
    timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!)

let date = try? Date("20220412", strategy: strategy) // nil :(
```

What is wrong with the `strategy` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.defaultDigits` doesn't work for `.year` with this date format, the reason is most likely because the format doesn't contain a separator so the parser can't automatically deduce the number of digits used for the year part.

If we try with a separator it will work fine. For example yyyy-MM-dd

```
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(
    format: "\(year: .defaultDigits)-\(month: .twoDigits)-\(day: .twoDigits)",
    locale: Locale(identifier: "fr_FR"),
    timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!)

if let date = try? Date("2022-04-12", strategy: strategy) { print(date) }
```

prints

> 2022-04-12 00:00:00 +0000

The solution for your format without a separator is to explicitly tell the strategy how many digits the year part contains using `.padded` (another option is `.extended(minimumLength:)`)

```
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(
    format: "\(year: .padded(4))\(month: .twoDigits)\(day: .twoDigits)",
    locale: Locale(identifier: "fr_FR"),
    timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!)

if let date = try? Date("20220412", strategy: strategy) { print(date) }
```

again prints

> 2022-04-12 00:00:00 +0000